# Magento 2 attribute position change

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes

I am trying to change position of attributes.I have created an attribute named custom tab , I am trying to set this attribute in top of product name.But by default this attribute show under More information Tab.

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info"  before ="product.info.sku">
       <arguments>
          <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
       </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check with this:

```
    <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.customtab" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="product.info.main">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getCustomTab</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">custom_tab</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">custom-tab</argument>
                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Well it's awesome @but content is align left side not able to mange with css  I want this top of product name

Comment: Please update answer @ why you delete latest answere

Comment: Now please check our updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code.

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.tab" as="custom" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" before="-">
       <arguments>
          <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
       </arguments>
    </block>
    <move element="custom.tab" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title" />
</referenceContainer>
```

***flush/clear cache**

Comment: Jothibasu@@can you update this answer with question @my mean can you include your answer in question

Comment: @sanjay - you can try the updated above code.

Comment: Jothibasu@@let me know how can use default attribute instead of custom atribute

Answer (score 0):

Please try it with another solution:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.customtab" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" before="-">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getCustomTab</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">custom_tab</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">custom_tab</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">custom_tab</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="custom_tab"</argument>
                    </arguments>
               </block>
            </referenceContainer>

    </referenceContainer>
```

It will be displayed below the product name
[image]

Comment: oK this is awesome@ custom tab need on top of product name

Comment: any help @regarding this